# Java JTabbedPane - Raised BevelBorder to selected tab

Tags: java, jtabbedpane, bevelled

How can I apply raised bevel border to selected tab in java JTabbedPane?

[image]

Comment: I suspect what you really want is a native look-and-feel.  Place `try { UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ReflectiveOperationException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }` at the start of your program, before any Swing components are created.

Comment: Yes, correct. Also I want to remove that unwanted blue border between tab and its content pane. How we can do this.